# Converting total irradiance forecast from cloud cover forecast using pvlib in python

Tags: python, forecasting, solar, pvlib

I am trying to calculate total irradiance in python using pvlib. In older versions the irradiation module included a method implementing Liu-Jordan model and it was possible to convert cloud cover forecast to irradiation forecast.

Would it be possible to perform this conversion in the latest version (0.3.3)?

Comment: Did you look at the source and issues? a quick google turned this up https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/pull/124 and https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/pull/180

Comment: I am using version 0.3.3 and module irradiance does not appear to inlude a method implementing Liu-Jordan model.

Answer (score 3):

An early prototype of the pvlib python forecasting feature conflated the Liu Jordan model with a cloud cover to transmittance model. This was on a github branch, but it was not part of an official pvlib python release.

pvlib python 0.4 includes the [`irradiance.liujordan`](http://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.irradiance.liujordan.html#pvlib.irradiance.liujordan) function, but you'll need to first convert cloud cover to transmittance. The `ForecastModel` class has a simple method for doing so.

For the pvlib python 0.4.x series, the essential code is

```
model = pvlib.forecast.ForecastModel()  # or any subclass of ForecastModel
irrads = model.cloud_cover_to_irradiance_liujordan(cloud_cover)
```

The pvlib python documentation also describes how to do this, though you'll have to look past the unrelated documentation errors on readthedocs (or build the documentation locally):

http://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forecasts.html#cloud-cover-and-radiation

The API may change in 0.5.